# Calculate Average Number of Days Between Multiple Dates

Tags: python, date, dataframe, grouping, average

Let's say I have the following data frame. I want to calculate the average number of days between all the activities for a particular account.

[image]

Below is my desired result:

[image]

Now I know how to calculate the number of days between two dates with the following code.  But I don't know how to calculate what I am looking for across multiple dates.

```
from datetime import date

d0 = date(2016, 8, 18)
d1 = date(2016, 9, 26)
delta = d0 - d1
print delta.days
```

Comment: To clarify, `value` for `A` in this case would be `(12/21/2016 - 10/21/2015) / 8` or 53.375?

Comment: @PineNuts0 I'm going to rollback the question since the answers no longer make sense (to your changed question). Please ask as a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this as follows in pandas (assuming the Date column is a datetime64):

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
  Account Activity       Date
0       A        a 2015-10-21
1       A        b 2016-07-07
2       A        c 2016-07-07
3       A        d 2016-09-14
4       A        e 2016-10-12
5       B        a 2015-11-24
6       B        b 2015-12-30

In [12]: df.groupby("Account")["Date"].apply(lambda x: x.diff().mean())
Out[12]:
Account
A   89 days 06:00:00
B   36 days 00:00:00
Name: Date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Since this python question is tagged data frame (and you talk about data frames) I figure it's pandas related...

Comment: Brilliant!  This worked perfectly; thank you so much :)

Comment: Followup question: how can I show just the days in the column and remove the timestamp piece?

Comment: @PineNuts0 `df.groupby("Account")["Date"].apply(lambda x: x.diff().mean().days)`

Comment: I have some blanks in my 'Date' column that show up as NaT...so when I try to run your suggested code above... I get the following error: AttributeError: 'NaTType' object has no attribute 'days'  ... any advice?

Comment: @PineNuts0 you should ask as a new question rather than updating old and answered question (This breaks StackOverflow for people trying to find  an answer to your original question.) I suspect you want to either ffill or drop the NaT dates.

Answer (score 1):

If your dates are in a list:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> dates = [date(2015, 10, 21), date(2016, 7, 7), date(2016, 7, 7), date(2016, 9, 14), date(2016, 10, 12), date(2016, 10, 12), date(2016, 11, 22), date(2016, 12, 21)]
>>> differences = [(dates[i]-dates[i-1]).days for i in range(1, len(dates))] #[260, 0, 69, 28, 0, 41, 29]
>>> float(sum(differences))/len(differences)
61.0
>>>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  my dates are not in a list...they are in a dataframe like the example I posted...how can I calculate given this format?